# Alternate ways of connecting to EWS on Android

Tags: java, c#, android, exchangewebservices

Where I work they want to make an app to display meetings scheduled on exchange on tablets outside of the meeting rooms. I have been tasked with making the app, and with no experience developing for android, I feel a bit lost.  So far, I have tried two different Java API libraries for Exchange Web Services, and the Microsoft EWS API for C#, and the compiled apk files making calls to EWS all crash on the tablets they want to use (Running android 4.0 and 4.4). I was wondering if there are any ways to pull meetings/make meetings on EWS without using an external library, or if anyone had a suggestion for an android specific API they know to work on android.

These are the ones that I have tried:

- [Java EWS](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api) (with the android wrappers people have made)
- [JWebServices](http://www.independentsoft.com/jwebservices/index.html)
- [EWS Managed API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220499(v=exchg.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EWS is just a SOAP web service so you can use any http client or other SOAP library to communicate, the hard part is when you don't use one of the libraries your talking about you need to create and parse all the SOAP request and responses yourself which is not that hard its just time consuming to build all the necessary code. The only other part is Authentication but if your using Basic Auth adding the Header is easy, NTLM is harder but again it just a header. If you don't have to use Java and you want to use C# xamarin and https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/ will work.

What might make it easier is forget about trying to run the EWS code on Android create a Hybrid App where your EWS code runs on a WebServer and just write a simple Android App that communicates with that WebSerivce, then the only thing running locally then is the Web code which shouldn't crash and it makes maintaining and updating your app really simple and you then have a more free choice as to what you can use to write the Web backend.